# Compare character of text files in php

Tags: php, text-comparison

Suppose I have two text files.

The first one, called `reference.txt` has the following content:

```
dog goat cat
```

The second one, called `compare.txt` has the following content:

```
cow goat cockroach
```

I want to compare each character in the 1st and 2nd text files and ignore the whitespace. I've been working it for weeks!

Hope anyone can help me out please. Just give an idea, sure it will be enough for me

Thanks

Comment: i think i have make it into a string, okey i just show u the code : 
<?php
  
  //a- 1st text
  $file = "sc_hLeong.txt";
  $f = fopen($file, "r");
 

        //c- fetch the content from website 
 $url = "https://www.hongleongonline.com.my/rib/";
        $str = file_get_contents($url);
        
 $myFile = "fetch_hLeong.txt";
        $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
        $stringData = $str;
 fwrite($fh,$stringData);
        fclose($fh);
  
  
?> I have compare it with sha1_file() but it's too sensitive. i just want to compare the characters only. urrh.

Comment: @lesta You should add the sample code as an update to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just thinking about doing comparison ignoring white spaces. Here is the general steps:

1. Read content of first file into a
2. Read content of second file into  a
   string
3. Eliminate all white spaces from both
   the strings( how? left for figuring
   out)
4. Do your comparison.

No code provided since you mentioned that you would like to try on your own.